# converting string or Series type to time only with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am very confused right now with types.
I recently moved to python from Rstudio.
Let's say

```
x = '20:05:20'
y = '20:06:10'
```

then x and y are just string, even though they refer times.
To get only time data without getting date, I often use

```
pd.to_datetime(df,format='%H:%M:%S).time()
```

pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M:%S').time()

```
datetime.time(20, 5, 20)
```

pd.to_datetime(y, format='%H:%M:%S').time()

```
datetime.time(20, 6, 10)
```

However after I make x and y as a dataframe, this code does not work anymore.
You can try if you want.

ttmm=pd.DataFrame({'ttme':[x,y]})
ttmm['ttme']

```
0    20:05:20
1    20:06:10
Name: ttme, dtype: object
```

pd.to_datetime(ttmm['ttme'], format='%H:%M:%S').time()
then I get this error massage.

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: If you want to access the datetime properties of a series, you can use `.dt`. In order to get just the time component, try: `pd.to_datetime(ttmm['ttme'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets answer your question: when performing `pd.to_datetime(ttmm['ttme'], format='%H:%M:%S')` you obtain a Pandas Series. If you want to apply a function to it, such as `time()`, yo probably want to do it like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(ttmm['ttme'], format='%H:%M:%S').apply(lambda x: x.time())
```

Now just two small things:

1. Maybe a small typo? (ttme instead of time):

   ```
   ttmm=pd.DataFrame({'time':[x,y]})
   ttmm['time']
   ```
2. The function `to_datetime` is smart enough to recognize the time without the format string most of the times. You can try without!

   ```
   pd.to_datetime(ttmm['ttme']).apply(lambda x: x.time())
   ```

Comment: Thanks!! It really helps me. brilliant!!

Answer (score 0):

although both used same function `pd.to_datetime`, but return different class object.
you can try it, and then you get it.

```
pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

returns:

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

if you read the source code, `pd.to_datetime` function return `DatetimeIndex` object,and `DatetimeIndex` object has the 'time' attribute.

But, `pd.to_datetime(ttme['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')` function returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series>
```

Series object has the attributes 'dtypes/values/name...' but 'time' not included. So `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'` message is absolutely right.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Now I think I know little more than I was.